# Are there any restrictions of nested Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, parallel-processing

Let's imagine some abstract code

```
    private void Main()
    {
        var workTask1 = DoWork1();
        var workTask2 = DoWork2();
        var workTask3 = DoWork3();

        await Task.WhenAll(workTask1, workTask2, workTask3);

        AnalyzeWork(workTask1.Result, workTask2.Result, workTask3.Result);
    }

    private async Task<object> DoWork1()
    {
        var someOperationTask1 = someOperation1();
        var someOperationTask2 = someOperation2();

        await Task.WhenAll(someOperationTask1, someOperationTask2);

        return new object
        {
            SomeOperationResult1 = someOperationTask1.Result,
            SomeOperationResult2 = someOperationTask2.Result,
        };
    }

    private async Task<object> DoWork2()
    {
        var someOperationTask3 = someOperation3();
        var someOperationTask4 = someOperation4();

        await Task.WhenAll(someOperationTask3, someOperationTask4);

        return new object
        {
            SomeOperationResult3 = someOperationTask3.Result,
            SomeOperationResult4 = someOperationTask4.Result,
        };
    }

    private async Task<object> DoWork3()
    {
        var someOperationTask5 = someOperation5();
        var someOperationTask6 = someOperation6();

        await Task.WhenAll(someOperationTask5, someOperationTask6);

        return new object
        {
            SomeOperationResult5 = someOperationTask5.Result,
            SomeOperationResult6 = someOperationTask6.Result,
        };
    }
```

Where 3 methods are being run parallelly and each of them consists of 2 parallel's operations. And result of 3 methods is passed to some method.

My question is there are any restrictions? Is it ok to have nested Task.WhenAll and what's difference between nested Task.WhenAll and one level Task.WhenAll operations?

Comment: You can have as many levels as u need. It shouldnt matter if its nested or not.
You might have some minimal overheap  when you are creating those nested tasks, but until you dont care about milisecond or two, it shouldnt matter.

Answer (score 3):

The only restrictions are the available memory of your system. The `Task.WhenAll` method attaches a continuation to each incomplete task, and this continuation is detached when that task completes. A continuation is a lightweight object similar to a `Task`. It's quite similar to what you get when you invoke the [`Task.ContinueWith`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.continuewith) method. Each continuation weights more or less about 100 bytes. It is unlikely that it will have any noticeable effect to your program, unless you need to `Task.WhenAll` tens of millions of tasks (or more) at once.

If you want a visual demonstration of what this method looks like inside, below is a rough sketch of its implementation:

```
// For demonstration purposes only. This code is full of bugs.
static Task WhenAll(params Task[] tasks)
{
    var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource();
    int completedCount = 0;
    foreach (var task in tasks)
    {
        task.ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            completedCount++;
            if (completedCount == tasks.Length) tcs.SetResult();
        });
    }
    return tcs.Task;
}
```

Comment: It also allocates an array for the list of tasks.

Comment: @PauloMorgado yep, true. I am saying about long term allocations though, not for allocations that are eligible for garbage collection immediately after the method returns.

Comment: Depending on the time the it takes to execute all tasks and the memory usage of the system, that array might be at Gen 2 when the "method" "returns".